# Generate RSA key pair with WebCrypto in Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, rsa, chromium, webcrypto-api

The following code works in Firefox 76.0.1:

```
"use strict"
let RSAKeys
(async () => {
  RSAKeys = await crypto.subtle.generateKey({
      name: "RSA-OAEP",
      modulusLength: 3072,
      publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
      hash: "SHA-256"},
    true,
// Chromium bug causes it to falsely complain that the array is empty. Sometimes adding "encrypt" helps.
    ["wrapKey"])
})()
```

but in Chromium 80 I get:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Usages cannot be empty when creating a key.

`["wrapKey"]` clearly isn't an empty array, so it seems to be a browser bug. Probably [this one](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=716729&q=component%3ABlink%3EWebCrypto). Can you confirm? And more importantly, do you know a workaround? (Adding the `encrypt` usage helped but only the first time, then the same error.) It has to be an asymmetric cipher supporting wrapping keys. According to the table in [the relevant chapter of the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/#algorithm-overview), RSA-OAEP is the only possibility.

Comment: Does it work in chrome 83 or newer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue on *Chromium* version 85.0.4162.0: The key usage `["wrapKey"]` generates the posted error message. But I can't reproduce that an adding of the key usage *encrypt* (i.e. `["wrapKey", "encrypt"]`) solves the problem (not even the fist time). However, with the addition of the key usage *unwrapKey* (i.e. `["wrapKey", "unwrapKey"]`) the error no longer occurs.

[`SubtleCrypto.generateKey()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/generateKey) returns a [`CryptoKeyPair`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CryptoKeyPair) for `"RSA-OAEP"` that contains the RSA key pair. If you look in the *Firefox* browser console at the key pair generated with the key usage `["wrapKey", "unwrapKey"]`, you can see that the key usage of the public key is `["wrapKey"]` and that of the private key is `["unwrapKey"]`. Both are plausible, since the public key is used for wrapping and the private key for unwrapping:

[image]

However, if you look in the *Firefox* browser console at the key pair generated with the key usage `["wrapKey"]`, you can see that the key usage of the public key is unchanged `["wrapKey"]`, while that of the private key is *empty*:

[image]

So *Chromium* prevents the generation of a key without key usage by the corresponding error message (which obviously refers to the private key with the empty key usage). In contrast to *Chromium*, *Firefox* obviously allows this.

Now is that a *Chromium* bug? Actually it makes not much sense to create a key without a key usage, because it cannot be used!

*Example for Firefox browser*: If the following code is executed in the Firefox browser, the key pair is indeed generated and a key is wrapped because of the key usage *wrapKey* for the public key, but the unwrapping fails with an `InvalidAccessError` if the key usage *unwrapKey* for the private key is missing:

```js
var test = async () => {

  try {
      
    var mode = document.querySelector('input[name="keyUsages"]:checked').value;
    var keyUsages = (mode === "wrap") ? ["wrapKey"] : ["wrapKey", "unwrapKey"] 
     
    // Create RSA key pair
    var RSAKeys = await crypto.subtle.generateKey(
      {name: "RSA-OAEP", modulusLength: 3072, publicExponent: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]), hash: {name: "SHA-256"}},
      true,
      keyUsages);
    
    // Create key to wrap
    var keyToWrap = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
      {name: "AES-GCM", length: 128},
      true,
      ["encrypt", "decrypt"]);
    
    // Wrap key
    var wrappedKey = await window.crypto.subtle.wrapKey(
      "raw",
      keyToWrap,
      RSAKeys.publicKey,
      {name: "RSA-OAEP", hash: {name: "SHA-256"}});
     
    // Unwrap key
    var unwrappedKey = await window.crypto.subtle.unwrapKey(
      "raw",  
      wrappedKey,  
      RSAKeys.privateKey, 
      {name: "RSA-OAEP", modulusLength: 3072, publicExponent: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]), hash: {name: "SHA-256"}},
      {name: "AES-GCM", length: 128},
      false, 
      ["encrypt", "decrypt"]); 
    
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Secret key for " + unwrappedKey.algorithm.name + " unwrapped.";
    console.log(unwrappedKey);
 
    } catch(e) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = e.name + ": " + e.message;
    }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 7.0em !important; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body height="200">
    <input type="radio" name="keyUsages" value="wrap" checked="true"> ["wrapKey"] 
    <input type="radio" name="keyUsages" value="wrapUnwrap"> ["wrapKey", "unwrapKey"] 
    <button onclick="test()">Run</button><br/> 
    <p id="result"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Therefore I would not classify this as a bug (but that's just my opinion).

Comment: Thanks for a detailed and well exemplified answer. The `"unwrapKey"` was indeed obviously missing.

My only nitpick is that if the spec mandates a different behaviour, that's a bug. But see also [my issue against the spec](https://github.com/w3c/webcrypto/issues/240).

Comment: While it's true that this error no longer occurs with `["wrapKey", "unwrapKey"]`, I'm getting a different one:
> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The key is not of the expected type

Comment: Well, I thought so, but I investigated further and actually not. I've discovered another difference between Chromium and Firefox. In Chromium the second error occurs when I try to export the key. I've asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62141756/export-rsa-key-pair-with-webcrypto-in-chromium) about it.