# Export RSA key pair with WebCrypto in Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, rsa, chromium, webcrypto-api

The following code works in Firefox 76.0.1:

```
"use strict"
let RSAKeys
(async () => {
  RSAKeys = await crypto.subtle.generateKey({
      name: "RSA-OAEP",
      modulusLength: 3072,
      publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
      hash: "SHA-256"},
    true,
    ["wrapKey", "unwrapKey"])
  alert(JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(
    await Promise.all(Object.entries(RSAKeys).map(async ([k, v], i) =>
      [k, await cryptoBase64("exportKey", ["pkcs8", "spki"][i], v)])))))
})()

async function cryptoBase64(primitive, ...args) {
  return ArrayBufferToBase64(await crypto.subtle[primitive](...args))
}

function ArrayBufferToBase64(buf) {
  return btoa([...new Uint8Array(buf)].map(x => String.fromCharCode(x)).join(""))
}
```

but in Chromium 80 I get:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The key is not of the expected type

Whence the difference? Is it a bug in Chromium? And is there a workaround?

(Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62113043/generate-rsa-key-pair-with-webcrypto-in-chromium). After applying the solution I still had a problem and it turns out there's another discrepancy between browsers I'm running into.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.entries` returns an array with the properties of the object as key-value pairs. The order of the key-value pairs is *arbitrary*, see [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

> The Object.entries() method returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable string-keyed property [key, value] pairs, in the same order
>   as that provided by a for...in loop...

and [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

> A for...in loop iterates over the properties of an object in an
>   arbitrary order...

On the other hand, `["pkcs8", "spki"][i]` assumes that the key order is private key (*i = 0*) followed by the public key (*i = 1*). In the Firfox browser the order matches coincidentally, in the Chromium browser not, which causes the exception.

The problem can be solved by *sorting* the array, e.g. using [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare), see also the recommendation in [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
sort((key1, key2) => key1[0].localeCompare(key2[0]))
```

Another approach would be to set the format (`pkcs8`, `spki`) depending on the key type (*private*, *public*) instead of sorting.

Your JavaScript code *completed with one of the two approaches* runs in both, the Firefox and the Chromium browsers:

```js
"use strict"

let RSAKeys
(async () => {
  RSAKeys = await crypto.subtle.generateKey({
    name: "RSA-OAEP",
    modulusLength: 3072,
    publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
    hash: "SHA-256"},
    true,
    ["wrapKey", "unwrapKey"])
  
  // Approach 1
  var result1 = JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(
    await Promise.all(Object.entries(RSAKeys)
      .sort((key1, key2) => key1[0].localeCompare(key2[0]))
        .map(async ([k, v], i) => [k, await cryptoBase64("exportKey", ["pkcs8", "spki"][i], v)]))))
  
  console.log(result1.replace(/(.{64})/g, "$1\n"));
  
  // Approach 2
  var result2 = JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(
    await Promise.all(Object.entries(RSAKeys)
      .map(async ([k, v], i) => [k, await cryptoBase64("exportKey", k == "privateKey" ? "pkcs8" : "spki", v)]))))
  
  console.log(result2.replace(/(.{64})/g, "$1\n"));

})()

async function cryptoBase64(primitive, ...args) {
  return ArrayBufferToBase64(await crypto.subtle[primitive](...args))
}

function ArrayBufferToBase64(buf) {
  return btoa([...new Uint8Array(buf)].map(x => String.fromCharCode(x)).join(""))
}
```

Comment: Wow, great catch, thanks! I knew it and even taught people such arcane nuances of ECMAScript, but somehow, as it often happens, it didn't occur to me as the source of a problem in my own code and I needed a fresh look from somebody else. Medice, cura te ipso… By the way, in this case a simple call to `sort()` is sufficient (though, depending on implementation, perhaps a little less efficient).

Comment: Also nice hint this: `replace(/(.{64})/g, "$1\n")`. Simplified: `replace(/.{64}/g, "$&\n")`.